# File has unexpected size (7660 != 7398). Mirror sync in progress?

Tags: updates

getting this error when running system update

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                                                                               
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease                                                                                                             
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                    
Hit:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                  
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                                                              
Hit:7 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/dev/ InRelease                                                                                                                       
Hit:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-proposed InRelease                                                                                                              
Get:9 https://brave-browser-apt-nightly.s3.brave.com stable InRelease [4,317 B]                                                                                                 
Hit:10 https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com focal InRelease                                                                                                                       
Hit:11 https://deb.opera.com/opera-developer stable InRelease                                                                      
Hit:12 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli focal InRelease                                        
Hit:13 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease                  
Hit:14 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                            
Get:15 https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_20.04 ./ InRelease [2,441 B]
Get:16 https://brave-browser-apt-nightly.s3.brave.com stable/main amd64 Packages [7,398 B]
Err:16 https://brave-browser-apt-nightly.s3.brave.com stable/main amd64 Packages
  File has unexpected size (7660 != 7398). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 99.84.126.35 443]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:7398 [weak]
   - SHA512:8bd5e753fce431f6e7cf8111722cd89c296598b62b335fd839e4c85c90d348a61347a456f3f8d117e3ae4c035cff797549eb2f4d5ecdccbc949d397c1b7e56ca
   - SHA256:bb14d8a13aac904ca0410bf622f7d062f3336273d94a7a33b881d223234f7167
   - SHA1:fe3f258c595be080b276763c160a04c4bc2f59ca [weak]
   - MD5Sum:6a2fa07708eb6be197aae80b61a5906c [weak]
  Release file created at: Sat, 31 Jul 2021 06:46:39 +0000
Fetched 6,758 B in 2s (3,237 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch https://brave-browser-apt-nightly.s3.brave.com/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages.bz2  File has unexpected size (7660 != 7398). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 99.84.126.35 443]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:7398 [weak]
    - SHA512:8bd5e753fce431f6e7cf8111722cd89c296598b62b335fd839e4c85c90d348a61347a456f3f8d117e3ae4c035cff797549eb2f4d5ecdccbc949d397c1b7e56ca
    - SHA256:bb14d8a13aac904ca0410bf622f7d062f3336273d94a7a33b881d223234f7167
    - SHA1:fe3f258c595be080b276763c160a04c4bc2f59ca [weak]
    - MD5Sum:6a2fa07708eb6be197aae80b61a5906c [weak]
   Release file created at: Sat, 31 Jul 2021 06:46:39 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution ... just wait several minutes and rerun the update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

evidently the prior update command ran in middle of system updates getting refreshed from upstream

Comment: Waiting for one day and then running `sudo apt-get update` again worked on my system.

Comment: I know this question is more than a year old, but I had some success doing `sudo apt clean`; my cached information was apparently wrong. Give it a try if you are reading this.